# aplay music player with python, start/stop code

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I am using python to write a small program that is supposed to play and stop a .wav file using aplay. I can get the file to play on the condition that button #1 is pressed, however I cannot seem to get the file to stop playing when button #2 is pressed. I have messed around with indentation and a couple other formats, but still have yet to achieve the desired result. I've included the base code that I first started with as it is the simplest. Any help would be wonderful, thank you! :)

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button
button1 = Button(22)
button2 = Button(17)
from time import sleep
import os
while True:
    def kill():
        os.system("pkill -9 aplay")
    def playsong():
        os.system("aplay test.wav6")
    button1.when_pressed = playsong
    button2.when_pressed = kill
```

Comment: Have you debugged? For example, does the `kill` function actually get called when  the button is pressed?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have tried that and it will call the function. I replaced the “os.system(...)” with the print command and the buttons preformed as they should. Upon pressing button one, the program would print “on” and button two yielded “off”.